# How to Add Another Directory (bundle) with jpackage After Installation Java Program

Tags: java, jdbc, jpackage

I'm using jpackage to create native Java installer **on Windows**. And also my app need a JDBC library (example `mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar`) to run the native app to connect the database.

I'm using NetBeans to build the app and after build, I saw the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar` are in `dist/lib` directory.

So that's mean, if I run `java -jar myProgram.jar` inside `dist` directory, the app will refer the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar` inside the `lib` library.

The directory in my project be like this:

```
dist/
  lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar
  myProgram.jar
```

This is the result after using jpackage and install the native app:

```
myProgram/
   app/myProgram.jar
   runtime/<the jre directory>
   myProgram.exe
```

And I run the app, I got error that JDBC class not found:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:186)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
```

I'm using this command to create the installer:

```
 jpackage \
--type exe \
--runtime-image minimal-jre \
--main-jar myProgram.jar \
--input target \ 
--win-console
```

So, my question is, how to bundle the `lib` folder so that `.exe` program can connect the JDBC class?

The documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

Answer (score 0):

I declared all dependencies (including the JDBC driver) to Maven or Gradle, and the tool on it's own would build the application jar and drop it together with all the dependencies in a lib folder. JPackage will use that lib folder to create a package - at runtime consider all these files to be on the classpath.

So if mysql.jar does not end up in that directory for you, maybe you want to run jpackage twice:

- Run jpackage to create an app-image. That is the directory structure before the actual packaging happens.
- Add your files into the app-image structure where you need them
- Run jpackage to finish building the package

With that you can customize a lot that jpackage does not offer out of the box.